# Good Documentation on Avaya IP Office 500 r2 setup

Tags: avaya

I have set up a couple of Avaya IP Office systems over the course of my current job. I have a pretty good handle on the process, but now I am faced with something I have not done before. Both the IP office systems I have set up used all Digital phones. The new system we are putting in place will actually use IP phones for the first time. After tyring to track down some general documentation on my own, I was not able to find anything that left me feeling comfortable about setting up IP phones on an Avaya IP Office 500.

Does anyone know of any good how-To's for setting up IP phones on IP Office? I get the impression its pretty simple but learend enough about Avaya to know that there are some tricky aspects to setting them up

Comment: Are the system manuals or Avaya support available to you? They're probably the best resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you accessed the Knowledge Base for IP Office?  If not, I would start there and select the manual that best fits.  http://marketingtools.avaya.com/knowledgebase/  Click on "IP Office Technical Manuals", then you'll see a series of drop down menus at the top of the page.  In the last box, choose "Manuals" from the list of choices.  A list of manuals will appear that provide instructions from various installations

Answer (score 1):

Some good links can be found here:

[ipofficeinfo.com information website](http://www.ipofficeinfo.com)

[tek-tips.com Avaya forums](http://www.tek-tips.com/threadminder.cfm?pid=940&page=1)